# Want to add twitter feeds to site.com

Tags: site.com

I want to display the twitter feeds on my site.com page. I have twitter id saved in my object. How can i display the twitter feeds on site.com. If any body have any idea how to get twitter feeds on site.com by using twitter id please guide me. I am not able to get any solution from this issue.

Answer (score 4):

Look at the [Twitter developer site](https://dev.twitter.com/) for information on the different predefined Twitter widgets such as [Embedded Timelines](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-timelines) and for information on more fine grained ways to get Twitter information such as the [Rest API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1).  The predefined widgets will generate markup that you can then paste into your Site.com widget, page, or page template in a [Custom Code Block](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=siteforce_code_custom.htm&language=en_US).  Note that this might be all that you need to do.  If you still think you need to get the Twitter account information from a custom object, I’ve outlined how you can get that data below and an alternative approach using a [Site.com Widget](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=siteforce_widget_overview.htm&language=en_US).

**Getting data from a custom object**

For your case where the values are stored on a custom object you can use a [Data Repeater](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=siteforce_data_repeater.htm&language=en_US) and a [Custom Code Block](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=siteforce_code_custom.htm&language=en_US).

- Make sure that the Site’s Guest User profile has the correct permissions for your custom object. You can access it through Site Configuration | SiteName Profile, or when you add the Data Repeater there is a link to get to the Profile.
- Add a [Data Repeater](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=siteforce_data_repeater.htm&language=en_US) that queries to get that exact record.
- Add a [Custom Code Block](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=siteforce_code_custom.htm&language=en_US) within that Data Repeater.
- Within that Custom Code Block you will have access to merge field(s) for that record that has the Twitter account information.

**Site.com Widget**

Site.com now supports [Widgets](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=siteforce_widget_overview.htm&language=en_US) which are reusable page independent sections.  You can store [properties (arbitrary name/value pairs) for a Widget](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=siteforce_widget_properties_about.htm&language=en_US) and then access them in your pages through merge fields.  You may want to consider this approach as opposed to querying from a Salesforce record.